# How can I write a state-dependent provider with Riverpod?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

Using the Riverpod framework, I have `providerB` of `bool`, which looks as follows:

```
final providerB = Provider<bool>((ref) {
  bool NewVal = true;
  // .... compute newVal
  return newVal;
}
```

I have been trying to write a new provider, `providerC`, which counts the number of `bool` that `providerB` has emitted. However, it appears that I am not allowed to modify a given provider from another provider (or from inside itself), so I failed to store and update the previous counter value.

What is the right way to write such a `providerC` and make it state-dependent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this illustrates what providerC needs to look like:

```
import 'package:riverpod/riverpod.dart';

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  ProviderContainer()
    ..listen(providerB, (_, cur) {
      print('B is $cur');
    })
    ..listen(providerC, (_, cur) {
      print('C is $cur');
    });
}

final providerB = StreamProvider(
  (ref) => Stream<bool>.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (i) => i.isEven),
);

final providerC = Provider((ref) {
  var count = 0;
  ref.listen(providerB, (_, __) {
    ref.state = ++count;
  });
  return count;
});
```

This is just counting state transitions, which for a bool is also you can count.  You won't ever get two "true" in a row or two "false" in a row.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, you have modified `providerB` and turned it into a `StreamProvider`. Is there really no way to store state in a provider or update a state-provider from another provider?

Comment: providerB was a StreamProvider in my example just to have a source of events, but it could also be a straight Notifier[Provider] with no change to this code.

Comment: Yes, I have verified that `providerC` works fine with either choice of provider. So, thank you, the problem is solved!